# How to get the statistics of Kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic, kafka-partition

We want to get the statistics for partition through the command or exposed API, like size of the partition , no of event in a partition for a topic.

Comment: Out of the box, Kafka doesn't expose this information, or have commands for it. You can SSH to a broker and `du` its topic partition directories, as one solution, but it's possible different replicas have different sizes (the leader partition will always be largest)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you please add this comment as an answer.